# Bourbaki-Witt to Tarski-Knaster Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, fixed-point-theorems

I was looking at the [Bourbaki-Witt Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki%E2%80%93Witt_theorem) which states that

> If $X$ is a non-empty, chain complete poset and $f: X \to X$ s.t. $f(x) \geq x$ for all $x$, then $f$ has a fixed point.

I was wondering if one could modify the proof of this theorem to prove a version of the Tarski-Knaster Fixed point theorem. Suppose also that $X$ has a minimum element $a$ and every subset of $X$ has a supremum. Let $f: X \to X$ be a monotone function i.e. $x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$. Then $f$ must have a fixed point.

Proof:
Define the functional:

$$
\begin{align}
g(0) &= a \\
g(\alpha^+) &= f(g(\alpha)) \\
g(\lambda) &= \text{sup}\{g(\alpha) : \alpha < \lambda\} 
\end{align}
$$

where $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal. If there is no ordinal $\alpha$ s.t. $g(\alpha) = g(\alpha^+)$ (which would be a fixed point), then $g$ must be a monotonically increasing function and is thus an injection from the ordinals into $X$ which is a contradiction.

The reasoning seems a little dubious to me so I would appreciate any thoughts!

**Edit:**

We can see $g$ is weakly increasing by noting that, since $g(0)$ is the minimum element, we have $g(0) \leq g(1)$. Then by monotonicity of $f$, we have $g(1) = f(g(0)) \leq f(g(1)) = g(2)$ and so on. This notion could be formalized via induction.

Comment: It may be because it's early in the morning, but is it obvious (or even true) that $g(\alpha^+) \geq g(\alpha)$?

Comment: @PatrickStevens You ask a good question. My reasoning might be flawed but I added a hand wavy explanation to the end of the question.

Comment: Applications: (1). (ZF). For every $y\in On$ there exists an infinite cardinal ordinal  $x>y$ such that $x$ is the $x$th cardinal.(I.e. $x$ is a fixed point of the Aleph function.)... (2). (ZFC). For every $y\in On$ there exists an infinite cardinal ordinal $x>y$  where $x$ is the $x$th strong limit cardinal ( A strong limit means $\forall z<x\;(2^z<x)$....)

Comment: Using $\alpha^+$ to denote anything other than the successor cardinal... is just bad.

Comment: Yes, this is common in very basic set theory books, but it is completely against the standard notation of advanced books, and research level set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Imre Leader uses $\alpha^+$ for the successor ordinal of $\alpha$ in the first course in logic and set theory in Part II. I trust him with my mathematical life.

Comment: @Patrick: Well... That is your pregoragive. I wouldn't trade places with you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this proof works.  When $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, you can prove $g(\lambda)\leq g(\lambda^+)$ as follows.  For any $\alpha<\lambda$, $g(\alpha)\leq g(\lambda)$ and hence $g(\alpha)\leq g(\alpha^+)=f(g(\alpha))\leq f(g(\lambda))=g(\lambda^+)$.  Since $g(\lambda)$ is the least upper bound of all these $g(\alpha)$, we must have $g(\lambda)\leq g(\lambda^+)$.